# How can you indicate files to ignore in svn when using git and the git-svn bridge?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, gitignore, svnignore

There is a master subversion repository that I've cloned a git repo from.  I've got a lot of ignored files in my .gitignore that I'd like the svn repository to know about.

I know that I can use `git svn show-ignore` to pull the ignored list from subversion, but how can I do the reverse?  Send a list of files to be ignored back to the svn repo?

Git version (and git-svn is at the same version):

```
git --version 
git version 1.7.0.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so one (annoying) method that I've found is to:

(convenience step) add the gitignore file to the repository so that it is tracked.

Do an `svn checkout`.

`svn propedit svn:ignore ./`

Add in all the stuff that's in the tracked gitignore file.

This is pretty ugly, though, and who likes to actually touch & checkout svn when you're working with git?  Anyone have a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Git svn does not support this, so you'd have to do it yourself on a separate svn checkout. From the manual:

> We ignore all SVN properties except svn:executable

It would be really nice though if this wasn't the answer...

Comment: What does "so you'd have to script it yourself" mean?

Comment: @Tchalvak, it means you'd have to do what you said (which can be scripted or not). I'll edit that as it doesn't add value to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your SVN repository. It acts like a concurrent-safe bridge and performs bidirectional translation (triggered by hooks). It translates SVN tags to Git tags, branches to branches, svn:ignores to .gitignore, svn:eol-style to "eol" and "text" attribute of .gitattirbutes, fully merged SVN branches to Git merge-commits; and vice versa.