# Do the entries in .gitignore get applied to the SVN repository when using git-svn?

Tags: git-svn, gitignore, svnignore

If I tell git to ignore x amount of files and never add them to the repository, will those files also make it into the svn:ignore property? And if so, how can I keep .gitignore local to only my local git repository?

*EDIT* Sorry about the duplicate, I searched on here and couldn't find anything on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, git will not do anything with svn:ignore.

From the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

> We ignore all SVN properties except svn:executable. Any unhandled properties are logged to $GIT_DIR/svn//unhandled.log

Also this [other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271449/how-to-set-subversion-properties-with-git-svn) is very similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `.gitignore` local to your repo, don't commit it.

Similar question:
[How can you indicate files to ignore in svn when using git and the git-svn bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2821608/275354)

Answer (score 0):

`git-svn` does neither .gitignore — svn:ignore, nor git attributes — svn properties conversion.

You may consider using [SubGit](http://subgit.com) instead. It does properly handle ignore, properties, merge-tracking data, etc. Among other things it works on a server-side, so one can use any Git client available to send changes to Subversion repository.

See [documentation](http://subgit.com/documentation/) and comparison with [git-svn](http://subgit.com/documentation/gitsvn.html).